# C# .NET Singleton life of app pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton, application-pool

I want to create a singleton that remains alive for the life of the app pool using HttpContent.Current.Cache.

Where would I create the class and how should it be implemented?  I understand how to implement a singleton but am not too familiar with threading and httpcontent.current.cache.

Thanks!

Comment: implement singleton pattern (no need to put the instance in the cache) - see Jon Skeet's excellent article about how to implement it in C#: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are over-complicating the issue? i'm not sure why you need to use the cache. Could you not just add a file to the App_Code folder to house your class e.g "mSingleton.cs"

```
public sealed class mSingleton
{
    static readonly mSingleton _instance = new mSingleton();

    public int MyVal { get; set; }

    public static mSingleton Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }
    private mSingleton()
    {
        // Initialize members, etc. here.
    }
}
```

Then it is global to all your code and pages, maintains state until the app pool recycles or there is a app rebuild (i don't know if this causes the app to recycle as well - if it does then it suits your criteria anyway), doesn't need to be added to any cache, application or session variables.. no messy handling

You can do this on page_load in any aspx.cs file and refresh it to see the count go up each time to prove state is maintained:

```
mSingleton getMyObj = mSingleton.Instance;
getMyObj.MyVal++;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks alot. This is a LinqtoUmbraco datacontext which is pulling data from a cached xml file. Apparently if there are more than 500 nodes in the xml file, when multiple users hit the site and many datacontext instances are created, performance suffers. I basically want a single datacontext to be created that is the same for everyone who hits the site. I imagine I will have to re-instantiate the dc when new data is added or updated or when the xml file changes... Does any of this change your advice? This object will be shared by all users who hit the site?  Thanks!

Comment: Personally i would not cache a data context as there could be some issues there. You can create the singleton as normal and just load the data in the class init? Add some nice helper functions to parse and query the XML as needed.

Comment: If the file access is a problem you don't want the data context loading the data up all the time anyway as it won't really solve the problem and if you are under that much load it's being loaded into RAM often and fast, possibly at times having multiple copies of the same data in RAM - So you might as well bite the bullet and leave it in RAM once, 500 nodes isn't a lot of ram at all - but you have to be careful about ram in shared hosting environments

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where to put the singleton code.

As soon as you access the `instance` and the type is initialized, it will remain in memory for the entire life of your `ApplicationDomain`. So use it as a normal class and the rest is done on first use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use the cache for this.  I'd recommend a static class or singleton with static getInstance().

Comment: I'd use a ConcurrentDictionary in a templated static class (assuming it's a bunch of data you'd like to cache).  Make sure app pool recycling is turned off if you want the data to stick around for more than 29 hrs (I believe that's the default).

Comment: Jordan is right on, the static class or singleton will be thread-safe, until you try to make it do something.  You can, for example, store data in your object in a way that is not thread safe.  A thread safe data structure or a few well-placed lock blocks and you'll be all set ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks alot.  This is a LinqtoUmbraco datacontext which is pulling data from a cached xml file.  Apparently if there are more than 500 nodes in the xml file, when multiple users hit the site and many datacontext instances are created, performance suffers.

I basically want a single datacontext to be created that is the same for everyone who hits the site.  I imagine I will have to re-instantiate the dc when new data is added or updated or when the xml file changes...  Does any of this change your advice?